# Create Data Binding not showing updated field from AppResources

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have two resx

```
AppResources.resx
AppResources.zh-Hant.resx
```

It just happened. I can not access strings I updated using the Search Properties panel.

```
Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.introText, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

But I can access it though the code.

```
AppResources.introText;
```

What I suspect is I have decided to migrate AppResources.resx with AppResources.zh-Hans.resx
Then I proceed to delete this file

```
-AppResources.zh-Hans.resx
```

Then I goto the Project Properties and disable the English support.
But I found that it keeps coming back as default(which is annoying).
After a while, I discovered I can access newly added string through the xaml way.
What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I need to build the project...
I am silly.